# cloned github repo into wrong path

Tags: bash, git, github

hello everyone I am new to Linux and of course bash by default. I have set up an Amazon light sail server, I am using the LAMP stack and to my knowledge, it doesn't have a GUI, so I had to use bash over SSH., not the end of the world except for I made a bit of a mistake and don't even know what to google.

I was trying to clone a Github repo into my htdocs folder. the problem is that I didn't cd into the folder first. the following

```
bitnami@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:~$ git clone https://github.com/myaccount/folder.git .
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

when I read this I realised what I did, then I cd'ed into the right directory and did deleted everything in there with the `rm -rf *` command. when I checked my webserver I knew something was wrong. instead of a blank `index of/` page, like normal it had a git item in it.

I then ran the command again to be sure, but it was still there.

I tried looking around within the file tree but I cannot find an extra or out of place git folder and would have no idea how to undo what I did.

when I run it properly it says:

```
bitnami@ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx:/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs$ git clone https://github.com/myaccount/folder.git .
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

thank you for your time

Comment: `rm -rf *` Wow, brave stuff. That kind of talk is a good way to erase your hard disk by mistake.

Comment: Note that the git folder is invisible. You won’t see it without something like `ls  -al`

Comment: @matt I did that, I can see the files. how do I delete them, also are these the files to delete, I just assumed they were.

Comment: When you are in the right place you can say `rm -rf .git` (carefully).

Comment: @matt it works, thanks